# Laravel collection with pivot data

Tags: laravel

i am trying to query a collection of many to many relations with pivot data

this is my route:

```php
Route::get('/test/{group}', function(Group $group){
    return $group->applicants->pivot->alert_end_date;
})->middleware('auth');
```

Models:

```php
public function applicants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'applicant_group_relationships', 'group', 'applicant')
        ->withPivot('alert_end_date');
}

public function applied_groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'applicant_group_relationships', 'applicant', 'group')
        ->withPivot('alert_end_date');
}
```

getting an error "Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance."

*edit: i am trying to get the applicants with the alert_end_date from the intermediate table as a collection as a whole.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Just `return $group->applicants;`?

Comment: Thanks! the data was collapsed and i did not see it! sorry i am really new to this. but Laravel is a really good framework even for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `return $group->applicants;`. This already contains the pivot data.